# [tag:celery [Connection reset Error either due to "connection to broker" lost or Could not receive ack

Tags: django, celery

I have a back ground task named task_conclude_key_issues_through_selenium, which will perform some click operations on a web page which takes about 3 to 5 mins.

I am getting any one of below error once celery back ground task execution is completed.

1.[2020-10-26 16:14:45,233: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last)
2.Couldn't ack 2, reason:ConnectionResetError(10054, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)

After 2 to 3 minutes,its getting connected to broker with following log message
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2020-10-26 16:23:07,677: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//

```
views.py:
--------
board_details_task_info = task_conclude_key_issues_through_selenium.apply_async(args=[created_pk])

tasks.py:
--------
@shared_task(bind=True)
def task_conclude_key_issues_through_selenium(self, created_pk):
     
settings.py:
-----------
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED=True
```

My Application uses below Packages:
1.celery - 5.0.1
2.celery_progress
3.Python - 3.6.2

Please let us know how to resolve these errors and proceed further.

Regards,
N.Dilip kumar.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has resolved with upgrading installation of celery and django_celery_results packages.
Installed latest version of celery & django_celery_results.
1.django_celery_results==1.2.1
2.Celery==4.4.7